# Protecting object attributes in Rebol

Tags: object, rebol, rebol3, rebol2, red

I'm trying something quite basic in Rebol. I want to have a simple instance hierarchy - a `question` base instance and some `question` sub-instances. And I want to have some instance attributes protected.

What I'm doing now is:

```
_question: make object! [
    id: none
    type: none
    text: none ]

    question-text: make _question [
        type: 'text

    new: func [
        id' [integer!]
        text' [string!]
    ] [
        make self [
            id: id'
            text: text'

            protect [ id type text ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

But then this fails:

```
qt1: question-text/new 1 "q-text1"
qt2: question-text/new 2 "q-text2"
```

Once I make the second instance qt2, I get:

> Script Error: Word id is protected, cannot modify

Next idea is then to move the protected fields out of `_question` and put them into `question_text` - even if I wouldn't like that.  But that just leads to the same error.

*Note: I'm currently doing this with Rebol2, but would ideally also get my things running in Rebol3 and in Red. And I would like to avoid hacks (sure - that's vague, things like Python `getitem()/setitem()` tricks would be fine). Then I'd prefer to have the fields unprotected.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some binding considerations here. This works, but is subject to the quirky nature of Rebol 2's `'protect` function and contexts:

```
new: func [
    id' [integer!]
    text' [string!]
    /local object
][
    object: make self []
    object/id: id'
    object/text: text'
    protect bind [ id type text ] 'object
    object
]
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't *protect* you from `new-question/id: 12` notation, just `do bind [id: 12] new-question`.

Comment: Thanks! Works as advertised and is just below the hack-threshold ;)